# rails controller private method error "cannot find album without ID"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I'm trying to display all albums in the albums#index page but I'm getting an error in my Albums controller "cannot find album without ID". I understand the issue is that there are no params, but I've used the find method with params[:id] a bunch of times in my app and haven't had this issue thus far.

For reference, Albums have many Reviews and have many Users through Reviews.
Users have many Reviews and have many Albums through Reviews.

I haven't built out my Reviews controller yet so that's unrelated.

Here is the error:

```
ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound in AlbumsController#index
Couldn't find Album without an ID
Extracted source (around line #40):
38
39
40
41
42
43


    def set_album
        @album = Album.find(params[:id])
    end

    def album_params

Rails.root: /Users/melc/review_project

Application Trace | Framework Trace | Full Trace
app/controllers/albums_controller.rb:40:in `set_album'
Request
Parameters:

None
```

Here is my Albums controller:

```
class AlbumsController < ApplicationController
    before_action :set_album, only: [:index, :show, :edit, :update]

    def index
        @albums = Album.all
        @current_user
    end

    def show
    end

    def new
        @album = Album.new
    end

    def create
        @album = Album.new(album_params)
        if @album.save
            redirect_to album_path(@album)
        else
            render :new
        end
    end

    def edit
    end

    def update
        if @album.update(album_params)
            redirect_to album_path(@album), notice: "Your album has been updated."
        else
            render 'edit'
        end
    end

    private

    def set_album
        @album = Album.find(params[:id])
    end

    def album_params
        params.require(:album).permit(:artist, :title, :avatar)
    end
end
```

Here is my albums#index view:

```
<h2>All Albums</h2>
<br>
<br>
<% if @album.avatar.attached? %>
    <image src="<%=(url_for(@album.avatar))%>%" style="width:350px;height:350px;">
<% end %>
<br>
<%= @album.artist %> -
<%= @album.title %>
<br>
<%= link_to "Edit Album", edit_album_path %><br><br>
<%= link_to "Upload a New Album", new_album_path %>
```

Here is the routes.rb file:

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do

  get '/signup' => 'users#new', as: 'signup'
  post '/signup' => 'users#create'
  get '/signin' => 'sessions#new'
  post '/signin' => 'sessions#create'
  get '/signout' => 'sessions#destroy'

  resources :albums do
    resources :reviews
  end
  resources :users

  root to: "albums#index"
  # For details on the DSL available within this file, see https://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html
end
```

Comment: It typically would not make sense to do a `set_album` for the index page, where I presume you're trying to display a list of albums. I say "presume" because that would be the typical index page, but the index page view you've shown doesn't display a list. In fact there is no value for `params[:id]` sent to the controller (`Request parameters: none` in the error message).

Comment: so remove `:index` from `before_action`. And then fix your index view to display the list of albums `@albums` that the controller#index method creates.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to change a couple things here:

1. on AlbumsController, you need to remove `index` from actions that "preload" an album

   `before_action :set_album, only: [:show, :edit, :update]`
2. You need to pass the album object to the route in the view:

   `<%= link_to "Edit Album", edit_album_path(@album) %><br><br>`

hope that helps

EDIT: about the avatar issue, looks like you're displaying the albums in the index, but you aren't iterating through them, something like:

```
<h2>All Albums</h2>
<% @albums.each do |album| %>
  <br>
  <br>
  <% if album.avatar&.attached? %>
    <image src="<%=(url_for(album.avatar))%>%" style="width:350px;   height:350px;">
  <% end %>
  <br>
  <%= album.artist %> - <%= album.title %>
  <%= link_to "Edit Album", edit_album_path(album) %><br><br>
  <br>
<% end %>
<%= link_to "Upload a New Album", new_album_path %>`
```

Comment: That helped thank you! but I got another error maybe you can help with? It's a nomethoderror for avatar in my albums#index view. any idea?

Comment: sure, let me expand my answer